# Custom Transition with "UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning" not working if "Present Modally" segue used

Tags: objective-c, uiview, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I'm having trouble using the technique found here: http://dativestudios.com/blog/2013/09/29/interactive-transitions/ while presenting the destination view controller modally.

When set to modal, it doesn't even call the delegate we've setup.

Is there some fundamental difference in Modal presentations that means this won't work?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should set the modal view controller to  UIModalPresentationCustom before displaying as the following code

modalVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;

here is a complete example project for displaying a transparent modal view controller with custom transition:

https://github.com/merocode-com/CustomTransitionExample